# Prove there are infinitely many integers n satisfying the congruence: $n \cdot (315)^n + 2022\equiv 0 \pmod p.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p \neq 3,5,7$ be a prime. Prove there are infinitely many integers n satisfying the congruence: $$n \cdot (315)^n + 2022\equiv 0 \pmod p.$$

---

What I have done/observed so far:

$315 = 3^2 * 5 * 7$ and $2022 = 2 * 3 *337$.

I can see that if for a prime there is a solution then there are infinitely many solutions. So for each prime we have to show existence of a solution.

Since $\gcd(315,p) = 1$ we have $(315)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$.

Let $n = k + (p-1)m = q + ps$, then $n \cdot (315)^n + 2022 \equiv n \cdot (315)^k + 2022 \equiv q \cdot (315)^k + 2022 \mod p$.

---

I am not able to proceed further to show existence of a solution.

Any hints will be helpful.

---

Source: This is a homework assignment.

Comment: Let $k= 0$ and let $q  -2202$. It now simply remains to show that $n = 0 + (p-1)m = -2202 + ps$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Is this a repost from the same person? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492492/let-p-neq3-5-7-be-a-prime-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-integers-n-s It is eerie that the same question would appear a few different times within a few days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the prime divisors of $315$ are $3,5,7$, we have that $315$ and $p$ are relatively prime.

Then by Fermat's little theorem,  $315^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

So settimg $n=20022(p-1)$,  we get a solution.

Then you can also check that for any $k$, we have solutions $n_k=n+kp(p-1)$.

Comment: 2022............